# Im trying to use a loop with python to provision ESXi hosts standard vSwitches

Tags: python-3.x

I have a working pexpect script that takes input to determine the vswitch name and which host IP.  My naming convention is standardized so what I'm trying to do is take a vswitch name input and append an incrementing value beginning with 1 and ending with a user input range end integer.

As seen below, if the input is ABC-SWITCH I would like the script to provision ABC-SWITCH1, ABC-SWITCH2, ABC-SWITCH3....  Can I append an integer/number/range to the variable newName throughout the script and run the command set for each?

```
import pexpect

print('Enter the name of the new vswitch: ')
newName = input()

print('Enter the IP of the host: ')
host = input()

pxp = pexpect.spawn('ssh ' + '-l ' + 'username ' + host)
pxp.expect('Password: ')
pxp.sendline('password')
pxp.expect('localhost')
pxp.sendline('esxcfg-vswitch -a '+ newName)
pxp.expect('localhost')
pxp.sendline('esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup add -p '+ newName + ' -v ' + newName)
pxp.expect('localhost')
pxp.sendline('esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup set -p '+ newName + ' --vlan-id 4095')
pxp.expect('localhost')
pxp.sendline('esxcli network vswitch standard set -v '+ newName + '-m 9000')
pxp.expect('localhost')
pxp.sendline('esxcli network vswitch standard policy security set -v '+ newName + ' --allow-promiscuous yes')
pxp.expect('localhost')
pxp.close
```

Comment: ... `newname + str(count)` and increase `count` inside your loop?

Comment: Ehh, couldnt get that working, seems its a function to purely count and cant be appended to a var str